# Mix Missing on OS X Mavericks

Tags: cpp-ethereum, mix, installation

I'm trying to install Mix-IDE on OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks), but failing.

I tried using the binaries for Yosemite from the [webthree-umbrella](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases) release page, but they crash on startup (pretty predictable).

Then I found out I can install cpp-ethereum [through homebrew](https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum). I can run eth, but Mix is missing from the Applications folder (yes, I used --with-gui flag).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Mix has been discontinued, so you might not be get it up'n'running anymore.

Comment: Mh... Ok... So it was removed from the brew but not from webthree-umbrella? Anyway, should I use remix now? In particular, I need a bytecode debugging tool...

Comment: Removed from the webthree-umbrella repo too, pimple.
See https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella.

Some alternatives are listed at http://solidity.readthedocs.org, while remix is coming to maturity.